# Assign a method to a instantiated sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2d Turret Defense game in C# and I have a question about the management of the updates of the turrets.
I want to create the menu over the turret sprite with several options for the upgrade.

My idea is to load the menu from the resources as sprite, assign it as child to the turret gameObject and then manage the comunication between the button to the turret to start the upgrade process.

**There is a way to assign a method/function to a resource freshly loaded?**

For example (in turret class):

```
Sprite myMenuButton = Resources.Load <Sprite> ("sprite_menu_to_load");
myMenuButton.OnMouseDown(){
// do something with the current turret's class
};
```

Or I have to save the gameObject sprite in resource folder with inside a script that will manage the OnMouseDown method searching the parent script of the turret and use the correct method?

For example (in menu sprite class):

```
void OnMouseDown(){
     GameObject parent = gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;
     turretScript parentScript = (turretScript) go.GetComponent(typeof(turretScript));
     parentScript.doUpgrade();
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Sprite itself (documentation may have information about it, did you already research there?)

But I don't see why you cant use Buttons instead of Sprite to handle this "menu behaviour" you wants to do. Button class have an onClick event handler that you can use to assign listners at runtime like

```
myMenuButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
   //handle click here
 });
```

you can also set methods by lambda expression, just google about it and you'll find a lot of resources to learn how to use it ;)

Comment: It can be a solution, I can create a Button in the turret script, assign a Texture to the button and put it near the turret. I will try it in the next days!

Answer (score 0):

first create a class which already implements the `OnMouseDown` and a list of function pointers and attach this class to every single item you are going to use it on beforehand.

```
public class MouseDownScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Action> Actions = new List<Action>();

    void OnMouseDown(){
        foreach(Action action in Actions)
            action();
    }
}
```

Then you have the ability to:

```
{
    Sprite myMenuButton = Resources.Load <Sprite> ("sprite_menu_to_load");
    // Cache the script
    MouseDownScript mouseScript = myMenuButton.GetComponent<MouseDownScript>();
    // Add anonymous actions with a lambda as such:
    mouseScript.Actions.Add(() => /*Any action here*/);
    // Add existing functions as such:
    mouseScript.Actions.Add(MouseDownAction));
}
public void MouseDownAction() {}
```

Comment: I'm trying your code but I get this message:  `Type 'UnityEngine.Sprite' does not contain a definition for 'GetComponent' ` , is something related to the Resources.Load<Sprite>

Comment: Sorry you have to get a hold of the `gameObject` which you want to absorb the click event. `GetComponent<T>()` only works from a `gameObject` or `MonoBehaviour`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Unity but you might be able to inherit from Sprite, add a property to it of type Action and assign that after you create it with Resources.Load

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new Sprite();
        s.Action = dostuff;
        // outputs Hello

        s.Action.Invoke();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void dostuff() { Console.WriteLine("Hello"); }

    public class Sprite
    {
        public Action Action { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add new class to Sprite when create Sprite

```
Sprite myMenuButton = Resources.Load <Sprite> ("sprite_menu_to_load");
myMenuButton.AddComponent<ClassForSprite>();

In ClassForSprite
    public class MouseDownScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        void onAction1(){
         //Code process for action 1
        }

        void onAction2(){
         //Code process for action 2
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e.aspx).

Basically you define a method signature e.g.

```
public delegate void ClickHandler();
```

then you define an instance of that signature:

```
public ClickHandler OnClick;
```

you can assign a method to OnClick on runtime and execute.
in turret:

```
public void ExecuteOnTurrent()
{
    // do stuff in turret
}

public void LoadSprite()
{    
    Sprite myMenuButton = Resources.Load <Sprite> ("sprite_menu_to_load");
    myMenuButton.OnClick= ExecuteOnTurrent;
}
```

in sprite

```
public delegate void ClickHandler();

public ClickHandler OnClick;

public void Update()
{
    //- detect click or other action
    if(click and OnClick!= null)
    { 
        OnClick();
    }
}
```